# How to add failed test's screenshots on RobotFramework Test Report?

Tags: jenkins, screenshot, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

When I start a Jenkins job, Robot Result Report is publishing at the end of job. But this report doesn't contain failed test's screenshots. How do I configure it?

Comment: Without information about your job configuration, it's hard to give a precise answer.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am currently having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Robot Framework plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin#RobotFrameworkPlugin-Basicconfigurationoftestingtask):

> If you have other artifacts such as screenshots that you want to persist for viewing later in the logs you must configure them under "Advanced... -> Other files to copy"

Comment: Sorry for my lately response. Here is the my configuration: [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/2d6wshg.png)

Comment: Possibly because the "Directory of Robot output" is an *absolute* path, and not a *relative* path, as the description under the field requires. It sounds like that field should be empty.

Answer (score 4):

Click the "Advanced..." button under your Publish Robot Framework results post build action and put `*.jpg, *.png` in the "Other files to copy" box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can delete the first line "Directory of Robot output" or maybe put a dot in it. 
It's said that you have to give the path relative to your workspace.

For your screenshots issue, try to put *screenshot*.png in "Other files to copy", because images name are "selenium-screenshot-X.png" so I guess your problem is with the "/" you put in the regex.